# coding for quarterly time series data in ggplot2 examples not found

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I have a time series variable from 2010Q1 to 2019Q4 converted using `ts()` function.

I want to do a ggplot2 graph for this one variable (value in the y-axis) to show year and relevant quarters in the x-axis (x-axis labes to look like 2010Q1, 2010Q2,…, etc).

I could not find an appropriate example or code to do this for quarterly data.  My try was:

```
ts_time <- tssl10qpm1[ ,1]  # to pick up the time series labels from my ts data set.

g_1 <- ggplot(tssl10qpm1, aes(x=ts_time, y=tssl10qpm1.GDP)) + 
       geom_line() +
       scale_x_date(format = "%b-%Y")
```

I know this is wrong ( b does not stand for quarters) : my error message:

```
Error in scale_x_date(format = "%b-%Y") :  unused argument (format = "%b-%Y")
```

When I try other variants, I get other error messages, like something to do with length of aesthetics, either 1 or same as data (which I do not understand at all).

My problem is very simple. I need few lines of code to get a simple graph showing quarterly labels on the x-axis which are associated with my y-values for the given quarters and years.

Answer (score 0):

To get quarterly breaks with labels formatted `%b-%Y` you would do this...

```r
scale_x_date(date_breaks = "3 months", date_labels = "%b-%Y")
```